# I am getting an empty list when writing the code below--I would have expected to a list to return

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is the code I used to extract the data using Selenium--I do see the xpath in the html located on the website so I do see the path needed to extract the element to create the list in the for loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3hyl.png)

I expected a list and there was no error to the code when ran.

Answer (score 0):

Issue you experienced probably related to site rendering.

You don't wait for container element to exist, so it can loop through empty list.

To wait for rendering you can use `presence_of_all_elements_located` with `WebDriverWait`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://audible.com/search")

data_containers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-widget*=product] .productListItem')))

for container in data_containers:
    title = container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bc-heading').get_property('innerText')
    author = container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'authorLabel').get_property('innerText')
    duration = container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'runtimeLabel').get_property('innerText')
    # and append them to your dictionary
```

Comment: Well, yes, but to get it's not mandatory for element to be visible. It should contain property innerText / innerHtml / etc.

In this case I think, waiting for visibility is redundant - waiting for presence works ok.

find_element AFAIK doesn't wait for anything, it's similar to $ or querySelector is JS.

Comment: Where do you see mention about visibility in my answer?) I haven't seen source code of `text` property in Selenium Python, but from my experience I know that getting native text property is more safe. And I don't understand, why my perfectly working answer with optimized selectors is downvoted. :)

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-10-11.html')
button_1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'visibleButton')
button_2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'invisibleButton')
print(button_1.text)
print(button_2.text)
print()
print(button_1.get_property('innerText'))
print(button_2.get_property('innerText'))

Comment: `.text` doesn't throw an exception for invisible element,  however, it doesn't get text - just returns empty string. It doesn't clear by default from this property and it's not something that expected from it. When I want to get text - I doesn't care about anything except element is exist. If I want to check visibility - I would call functions that wait for visibility. 
So, I can assume that using `text` property is not safe from point of stability and bad practice.

Comment: You are right... `.text` doesn't throw on an invisible element. I'm not sure when that changed. I just tested C#, Java, and python and none of them threw but they do return empty string as you said. It's still better to wait for visible instead of presence because there's not much point in printing empty string instead of the actual string.

Comment: In case of using `.text` - yes, agree. For future I know now, that safer is to get text by `get_property` when you care just about text

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of your script is. If your script just performs some actions then yes, `get_property` has no consequences. BUT... if your script is a UI test then you should avoid using `get_property` and other JS functions because they shortcut around what an actual user can do. For example, if you use a JS click to click some button and one day the page isn't in the right state and the button is not visible, the script will work anyway but a user couldn't click the invisible button. That's a false positive and dangerous in a UI test.

Comment: I deal in UI tests on a daily basis. I never use JS unless it's absolutely necessary because it's safest to avoid them for UI tests so you aren't testing some scenario that a user can never complete. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The code is not finding all the elements only pulling the last one when I print title, it only prints the last element on the page

Comment: Also, the get property is not working--it is saying it is an Attribute Error 'list' object has no attribute 'get_property'

Comment: @JeffC I am dealing with them too (last 4 years more close to Puppeteer / Playwright than Selenium) and I never had problems with JS native properties that get text. I had problems with visibility props / disabled / checked props, etc. But not text. For example, if you have some custom element that actually is invisible, but text is visible for user (it's rendered by another component that has only reference to invisible component), `.text` it would be false - negative case.

Comment: So it's case related. :) If you don't have such cases - visibility condition is good practice.

Comment: @ChanceJennings Based on your comments I have strong feeling that you haven't executed my code as is, only copied some part of it to yours, loosing context.

Comment: I have figured it out--I will post my code this evening---@Yaroslavm you really helped me out with this--and you are right I did combine the code but I needed to index the text that the website was pulling from so that it could pull from the